# Multiple Cordova apps within a single Cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid

I have a few html5 / JS  projects that need to be invoked by different clicks from the homepage, 
1. The first page (Page 1) would be a list of apps - App1, App2, App3 and so on,
2. If I click App1 the Project1 should be invoked, (Project 1 can be an independent www resource of Cordova as well); App1 needs to be downloaded in the from the server(future plan)
3. Likewise, Coming back to the homepage when App2 is clicked the Project3 should be invoked. 
4. So Page 1 works like a container which has App1, App2 and so on and respective projects are loaded when they are clicked,

I have been working with SPA in Cordova, now I need to merge all these projects.
As this should be a loosely coupled architecture, the app shouldn't be a website using a folder or file system method. These are different projects.

No code started.
[image: Check out this basic architecture diagram.]

Comment: Just to understand what you want to achieve - is it similar how Facebook app and Messenger app?

Comment: No, let me explain you in a better manner. Points to remember. I have HTML javascript projects that can be independently made as apks/IPA using Cordova - App1, App2 and so on. And in the home page of the app is the list of such apps.  The homepage acts as a container for all the apps.

Comment: So, by clicking on the list item - your app 1,2... should be opened?

Comment: @Cheese Yes, as apps are independent in nature, when I click App1, I need open App1 and respectively for other apps. Why it needs to be independent because - later in case I have to update one of those Apps internally, I need to change it independently without touching other app.

Comment: @RavindraPawaskar did you find any solution to this issue?

Answer (score -2):

The answer is deep linking. E.g. you know when, you want to launch mail app you trigger "mailto:", when web "http:". So your apps should implement some protocol, that you will call from main app, to open your sub apps.

For example, you will call "app1:" and app1 will open

Comment: I totally understand the concept of Deep linking, but the Apps which I said - App1, App2 are not external apps. They reside in the main App itself. I just said the apps can be built using Cordova independently to say those are loosely coupled. While they reside in the same main app. Calling a certain package/android app (like facebook or twitter or any other app may be connected with Deeplinking while I hit the URL of a certain website and I can open the native app itself). App1, App2 and so on are inside the same main app.

Comment: I have updated my question with an image as a basic architecture diagram which you could refer.